# Laravel 8 livewire hide menu component when task finished or page clicked outside of it

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

My issue, I have a table with Accounts in it and the last column is a livewire component. Currently I can click outside of this and it doesn't hide. The component itself is meant to be a clone of the Manage Account dropdown when logged in (using jetstream).

My code:
resources/views/livewire/account-menu-component.blade.php

```
<div>
    <div class=" focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-300 transition hamburger" wire:click="$toggle('showDiv')" title="Click to show menu">
        <i class="fa-2x fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    @if ($showDiv)
    <div class="absolute z-50 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg origin-top-right right-0 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 py-1 bg-white">
        <div class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-gray-400">
            {{ $account->name }}
        </div>
        <a class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 "
           href="{{ URL::to( 'accounts/' . $account->id . '/edit' ) }}">Edit
        </a>
        <a class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100"
           href="{{ URL::to( 'accounts/' . $account->id . '/destroy' ) }}">Delete
        </a>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

app/Http/Livewire/AccountMenuComponent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class AccountMenuComponent extends Component
{
    public $account;
    public $showDiv = false;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.account-menu-component');
    }

}
```

in the final `td` of the tables row in my index.blade.php file is `@livewire( 'account-menu-component', ['account' => $value] )` where `$value` is the account data for the row itself.

If i click on the row outside this component(or on another row or if i click on another hamburger for another row) it remains open and the only way to close it is to click the hamburger icon again.

So how can i close this if I click outside this component and also when one of the anchors within it is clicked? I'd prefer a livewire solution rather than a javascript/jQuery example that would require adding id elements etc. The menu used by Jetstream while logged in behaves exactly as I require.

Any ideas?

thanks

Craig

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I discovered i could do the following amends which worked as desired (but having it fade would of been nice)
resources/views/livewire/account-menu-component.blade.php

```
<div>
    <div class=" focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-300 transition hamburger" wire:click="$toggle('showDiv')" title="Click to show menu">
        <i class="fa-2x fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    @if ($showDiv)
    <div x-on:click.away="if($wire.get('showDiv')==true) { $wire.hideDiv() }" class="absolute z-50 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg origin-top-right right-0 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 py-1 bg-white">
        <div class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-gray-400">
            {{ $account->name }}
        </div>
        <a class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 "
           href="{{ URL::to( 'accounts/' . $account->id . '/edit' ) }}">Edit
        </a>
        <a class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100"
           href="{{ URL::to( 'accounts/' . $account->id . '/destroy' ) }}">Delete
        </a>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

I then added the hideDiv function to the AccountMenuComponent file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class AccountMenuComponent extends Component
{
    public $account;
    public $showDiv = false;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.account-menu-component');
    }

    public function hideDiv() {
        $this->showDiv = false;
        return view('livewire.account-menu-component');
    }

}
```

Hope this helps someone else. It seems Laravels livewire developers have no intention of introducing this feature.